# Authorize.Net API, AIM & ARB - US Based Business - Taking international credit cards

Tags: internationalization, e-commerce, authorize.net

I'm currently setting up a recurring billing system that will support recurring billing (ARB) & transactions (AIM).  The question I'm asking is, is it possible to accept international payments? I am from the United States, setup with a bank in the United States.  Basically saying, can someone from France, London, Africa, China, etc. purchase on my site?

Comment: You should ask Authorize.net's support about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not be an issue with Authorize.Net. Your issue would be with your merchant account provider. International transactions, especially from countries that do not perform AVS and also that have higher rates of fraud, are higher risk and many merchant account providers either do not allow international transactions or need to know that they will be occurring up front before approving the account.

Additionally, all transactions occurring through Authorize.Net must be in US dollars so if you do accept international orders you must convert them into US dollars before processing those payments.

Comment: So when you say "merchant account provider". I'm not quite sure what you mean. I basically have to make sure my bank will accept transactions internationally? I thought authorize took care of that?

Comment: Authorize.Net is only a payment gateway. They connect the merchant account provider to a website. They basically act like a credit card machine does in a retail store. Without a merchant account they can't do anything.

Comment: Also, what would be a proper merchant account provider I could get to have this work correctly?

Comment: There are so many merchant account providers that I really couldn't say who is good and who isn't. The best advice I could give you is to be sure to shop around. Rates and fees will vary a lot so get at least three quotes before committing to one. Definitely do the math to figure out which one will cost you less overall. The sales agents for merchant accounts can be sneaky so unless you actually figure out your real costs you don't really know which is the best one for you.

Comment: And thanks for the compliment! I'm working on some new stuff to make working with ARB easier. If I can ever still down long enough to finish it I hope to publish it soon.

Comment: Cool, I'm not really sure where to start looking to be honest?  Do you have a company or site I could reference?

Comment: http://www.creditcardprocessing-r-us.com/International_Credit_Card_Processing/

Something like this perhaps?

Comment: If you can't get a US-based merchant account you can go there but try to get a US based one first. They're **a lot** cheaper.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6234/discussion-between-wes-and-john-conde)